# Attaching conditional AND condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to have an `AND` condition attached to my `WHERE` clause based on some condition. Below is the situation I am facing

```
DECLARE
    @param1 INT, @param2 INT

SET @param1 = 1
SET @param2 = 1

SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.a = t2.b
INNER JOIN TABLE Table3 t3 ON t3.c = t2.d
WHERE t1.id = 1
  AND t2.id = 2
```

Here is where i want the condition to come in--

```
Case when `@param1 = 1` and `@param2 = 1` THEN `AND t3.id = 4`
```

But I guess and does not work like this ? :/ Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your where clause

`and isnull(t3.id,'') = case when @param1 = 1 and @param2 = 1 then 4 else isnull(t3.id,'') end`

Comment: No sweat. isnull is essential since null <> null. Just FYSA.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2 and
      ((@param1 = 1 and @param2 = 1 and t3.id = 4) or
       not (@param1 = 1 and @param2 = 1)
      )
```

This does assume that the parameters are never `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following as an `AND` condition to check if `t3.id = 4` when `@param1` and `@param2` both equal `1`, or no additional condition if they don't:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.a = t2.b
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.c = t2.d
WHERE 
    t1.id = 1
    AND t2.id = 2
And
(
    (
        @param1 = 1
    And @param2 = 1
    And t3.id = 4
    )
    Or
    (
        @param1 <> 1
    Or  @param2 <> 1
    )
)
```